# It it ok for a 15 months old to fill her mouth with food?

Tags: toddler, food

Is it unusual for a 15 months old to fill her mouth with food? She does this fairly often, especially with food she likes, then she realizes her mouth is too full and spits.

We tell her to chew and to take a piece at a time, or to bite off chunks, but it doesn't work every time.

I don't know if this is relevant, but she has always been a fast eater, she was breastfed and it took her about 10 minutes for a full meal

Comment: Clearly, it is pretty common! :)

Comment: Thanks, had searched but clearly I didn't use the right keywords! 
Seeing that it's pretty common and that it's usually just a phase is reassuring :)

Answer (score 0):

My daughter is one and she was doing this as well. However I teach her to wait until she is done chewing then to proceed with more by making her say Ahhh after she has put food in her mouth now she has the hang of it. It was a headache at first but I'm glad we have passed this. Key thing you have to make it fun hope this helps a Lil.